# Collect seperate data from the two microphones in Google Glass

Tags: android, signal-processing, google-glass, microphone

I am wondering whether it's possible to collect data from the [two microphones present in Glass](http://www.catwig.com/google-glass-teardown/) separately and use it for computing operations? Like for example, sound localization.

I know that that there is an API to [use the microphone as Audiosource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html) and somebody has done it too [here](https://github.com/googleglass/gdk-waveform-sample) (although I haven't verified it), but from which microphone is the data coming from here? Or is it that Audiosource API uses both microphones to collect data, perform noise cancellation and then return it? If that is so, would it be possible further go down the abstraction and access the two mics separately?

Since, this is not so popular on the web(to the best of my knowledge), any insights regarding this would be welcome.

Thanks --
HD